# Amazon RedShift Drop Default

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I want to add a NOT NULL column to a table in RedShift.  To do this, I specify a default so that existing rows know what to put in the new column.  But I don't want a default on this column - if no data is supplied in my COPY command, I want it to fail.  In Postgres I could do this:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN my_column DROP DEFAULT;
```

However Redshift gives me an error saying `ERROR: ALTER COLUMN SET/DROP DEFAULT is not supported`.

What is the correct way to add a non-null column, update existing rows, and not have a default?

UPDATE: It seems Redshift [won't allow any ALTER COLUMN statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29536916/redshift-how-to-remove-not-null-constraint).  Does that make this impossible?

Comment: See `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29536916/redshift-how-to-remove-not-null-constraint`

Comment: Or using a hyperlink- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29536916/redshift-how-to%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B-remove-not-null-con%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bstraint

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

- Create a new table with you new schema (including the NOT NULL)
- INSERT INTO new_table with your pseudo-default hard-coded
- Drop the old table
- Rename the new one

e.g

```
CREATE TABLE new_table 
(column_1 type, column_2 type, new_column type NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO new_table (column_1, column_2, new_column)
SELECT column_1, column_2, 'default_value' FROM old_table;

DROP TABLE old_table;
ALTER TABLE new_table RENAME TO old_table;
```

Answer (score -1):

You should choose the not null value for zero for example,

```
alter table my_table
      add column my_column int default 0
```